# Is this possibly Arum?

Tags: identification

If so, any guess which? This is in my woods in the North Carolina mountains, late September. None other around that I see. I just spent quite a while removing invasives (the usual aggressive ones).[image]

Comment: I would have identified it as Jack in the pulpit, Arisaema triphyllum, except it lacks the distinctive spathe

Comment: If it was in Europe I would have guessed *Arum maculatum* but that doesn't seem to be native to the USA. The spathe may have disappeared before the berries became ripe and noticeable.

Comment: If it is either of the above, note that ALL parts of the plant are poisonous and irritate skin.

Comment: Because of the three-part leaf and upright seed stalk, I'd go with an Arisaema (the spathe would've been gone a month ago or so). Usually, though, A. triphyllum usually has a much fuller seed head. Since no arum is native to NC, I'd go with A. triphyllum. @kevinsky, you should convert your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the pictures and think this is Jack in the pulpit or [Arisaema Triphyllum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arisaema_triphyllum).

The identification keys are that:

- native to eastern North America from Nova Scotia to Florida and including USDA zone 4 where I live
- close relative, Arisaema dracontium, has quite a different leaf shape but overlaps the range
- cluster of bright red berries in the fall
- the spadix and spathe that flower are only seen from May to June  (Thanks Jurp!)
- leaves appear to be trifoliate

As alephzero has pointed out the plant is toxic if ingested due to the calcium oxalate (which is also [found in tea leaves and kiwi fruit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_oxalate)).  You would probably have to eat the whole plant underlining that [the dose makes the poison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_dose_makes_the_poison).

I have one in my garden and find that even if you try and spread the berries it takes many years before you see a mature plant.  It does not spread aggressively and seems quite happy in dry shade.